# How do I create a new directory called duplicates if a file already exists when renaming in c shell

Tags: shell, csh

I have a script that renames files with.JPEG ext to .jpg but if it renames one and it already exists I need it to create a new directory called duplicates and move the file there instead of overwritting it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this:

```
foreach j (*.JPEG *.JPG)
    set target = $j:r.jpg
    if (-e $target) then
        mkdir -p duplicates  # create directory if it doesn't already exist
        mv $j duplicates/$target
    else
        mv $j $target
    endif
end
```

But consider whether csh is the best tool for this kind of thing:

http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to test for the existance of a file:

```
test -e img.jpg
```

You can test the existance of a file and if it does exist then move it to the duplicates folder. To create a folder called duplicates do the following:

```
mkdir duplicates
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `foreach j ( *.JPEG *.JPG) 
mv $j $j:r.jpg 
if(test -e $j)
mkdir dups`

Comment: You wouldn't normally use the `test` command in a csh script.  csh has its own built-in `-e` operator.